# vb desktop icon different from application icon

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to set the icon of my application. I set the icon once before by changing the property of the form and the property of the project. Now I am trying to change the icon to a different one. The icons of the form and the application have been successfully changed, but when I copy the application to the desktop, the desktop icon still remains the previous one. Can anyone please tell me how to change the desktop icon?

Thanks,
Kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the icon properly on the form it should get visible in the Taskbar immediately as soon as you start your application.

However even if you did change the project icon properly and therefore your executable has the correct (new) icon (check that in your \bin-folder) you can get the wrong (old) icon from the desktop because you system might retrieve it from the icon cache.

Please check the following link to understand that topic and to see how you can enforce windows to renew its icon cache.

- Win 7--: http://www.winability.com/repair-windows-desktop-icon-cache/
- Win 8++: http://www.winability.com/how-to-erase-icon-thumbnail-cache-windows-8/

Comment: Thanks very much, @Waescher. That solved my problem!